# CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX environment variable - doesn't work?

Tags: c++, cmake

Some info sources say:

> You can change the installation directory (prefix) by setting the
>   CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX environment variable

If i do in a file:

```
export CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$KDEDIR
```

and then source it, and check if `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` environment variable is set, when i do:

```
vic@wic:~/kde/build/kde-workspace$ cmake ../../src/kde-workspace/
```

and then:

```
vic@wic:~/kde/build/kde-workspace$ make install
```

it tries to install files to system directories.

If i specify `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` as an argument to cmake:

```
vic@wic:~/kde/build/kde-workspace$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$KDEDIR ../../src/kde-workspace/
```

then `make install` works ok - installs files to `$KDEDIR`

Is the documentation wrong about the possibility to set environment variables with the same name, or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) has to be set as a CMake variable:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/path/to/installation/directory ..
```

But CMake also [supports using](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/DESTDIR.html) the `DESTDIR` environment variable:

```
export DESTDIR=/path/to/installation/directory
make install
```

Comment: Although CMake does use `DESTDIR` if it is set, it does not then ignore `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`; instead it concatenates them. So with this example you end up installing to `/path/to/installation/directory/usr/local/`. Of course you can set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to nothing, but if that were a useful possibility then you might as well just set it to the desired path.

Answer (score 4):

CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is a CMake variable, not an environment variable. It can be set with `cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=yourpath`